# How to visualize telecom churn analysis using hostogram or scatterplot in ipython

Tags: machine-learning, ipython, histogram, scatter-plot, pyspark

I have processed output for `churn` analysis in telecom industry where in following format:

`labelsAndPredictions = testData.map(lambda lp: lp.label).zip(predictions)`

Where in if I print it the output looks like this:

`[(0.0, 0.074), (0.0, 0.132),(1.0, 0.853),.....]`

As you can see each element has two parts - a `label` and a `prediction`. For example the 1st element has label `0.0` (or 0) and its prediction is `0.074` (in other words it has `7%` chances of churning(or switching to other network)). The features I used in training my model is a set of 5 different features.

Now I want to visualize this output (the prediction) in `ipython` using `hostogram` or `scatterplot` but I am having difficulty in understanding how to plot the above result in `histogram` or `scatterplot` in `ipython`

Comment: Is there any particular reason you want to use D3 instead of, say, a static matplotlib plot? Do you need interactivity in the plot?

Comment: @santon I have modified the post accordingly. A scatterplot or histogram will suffice the purpose

Comment: I think this question would be better adressed in the more specific QA site Telecommunications proposed here as the concept of Churn is very specific to this industry: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/104688/telecommunications
If you like the proposal, ask your question there and follow the proposal as well